# How can I change this code from Uart to I2c device

Tags: python-3.x, raspberry-pi, uart, i2c, converters

I have code for a PMS5003 air quality sensor that works fine over uart on a Raspberry Pi
I now have the I2C version of this sensor and I'd like to get the code working via I2C instead of serial port
I'm still really new to Python and not sure how to do this
Can anyone help?

This is the section of the code that's relevant

```
import struct
import time
import pdb
import threading
import logging
import sys
if sys.platform != "win32":
    import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

__version__ = '0.0.1'

PMS5003_SOF = bytearray(b'\x42\x4d')
MIN_FRAME_LENGTH = 28

class ChecksumMismatchError(RuntimeError):
    pass

class ReadTimeoutError(RuntimeError):
    pass

class SerialTimeoutError(RuntimeError):
    pass

class PMS5003Data():
    def __init__(self, raw_data):
        self.raw_data = raw_data
        self.data = struct.unpack(">HHHHHHHHHHHHHH", raw_data)
        self.checksum = self.data[13]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.__repr__()


class PMS5003():
    def __init__(self, serial, pin_enable=22, pin_reset=27):
        """pin_enable and pin_reset are really GPIO ids, not pin numbers on the Pi header."""
        self._serial = serial
        self._pin_enable = pin_enable
        self._pin_reset = pin_reset
        self.data = None

        self.setup()

    def setup(self):
        if (self._pin_enable is not None) and (self._pin_reset is not None):
            GPIO.setwarnings(False)
            GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
            GPIO.setup(self._pin_enable, GPIO.OUT, initial=GPIO.LOW)
            GPIO.setup(self._pin_reset, GPIO.OUT, initial=GPIO.LOW)


    def getData(self):
        """Get most recently retrieved consistent set of data."""
        #self.lock.acquire()
        data = self.data
        #self.lock.release()
        return data
```

I do NOT need the reset and enable pins on the I2C version as these functions are not used

Can anyone tell me what I need to do to get this working on the Pi using SMBUS2?

I already have another device working using the SMBUS2

I will need to add something like this I guess

```
import smbus2
import struct
import time

class PMSA003
    """Python I2C driver for the PMSA003 Air Quality Sensor."""

    def __init__(self):
        self._i2c_addr = 0x0x12 #I2c Address used for this device
        self._i2c = smbus2.SMBus(1)
```

Can anyone tell me how to get the device to read using I2c instead of the Serial it was using?

Comment: Easiest and better way is to enable a driver (https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/iio/chemical/pms7003.c) in the kernel and use it via IIO subsystem (https://wiki.analog.com/resources/tools-software/linux-software/libiio).

Comment: That might be a good idea apart from a few things. As I said I'm really new to Python and would have no clue how to set up an i/o subsystem.
Also the driver you listed uses Uart not I2c, it also sends to commands to tell the device to sleep, wakeup,send passive mode and read passive.
The I2c version does not need these. It sends continious data, all I need to do is somehow tell the program to use the SMBUS2 and to read the data coming from I2C address 0x12

Comment: Indeed, I haven’t noticed that it is only for serial interface. Btw, have you link to a Datasheet of i2c variant? (I was talking about IIO subsystem. It stands for “industrial i/o”)

Comment: https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/product-files/4632/4505_PMSA003I_series_data_manual_English_V2.6.pdf
 it's identical to what you listed but the sleep/reset commands are not used as the pins are not connected. only the sda and scl pins are used.
I have code to extract the data, I just need to know how to get the Pi to read the data from SMBUS2

Comment: Thanks. Are you sure you don’t need reset and set pins to be connected? Datasheet says it should be. In any case they provide the data file with random access for any of the registers. It uses automatic address increment AFAICT. I guess it’s quite easy to introduce a driver in the kernel for everybody. But you may code in Python if you wish.  They even refer what to use as a reference, I.e. 24cXX eeprom protocol. Try to google for examples. (I still think that in-kernel version is a right thing to do)

Comment: Okay, pins can be left unconnected. But default mode is active, how to switch to passive? What active means in case of i2c? Seems it missed some information.

Comment: Yes I'm positive. It defaults to active mode and sends data automatically after power up.
I have code for this device but it used Micropython and that doesn't work on the Pi 3 or 4 as it uses from machine import Pin,I2C.
https://github.com/ZIOCC/Zio-Qwiic-PM2.5-Air-Quality-Sensor-Adapter-Board
The Adafruit example code on their website works but never works after power up, only after the 2nd time running and that isn't useful to me and I'd rather not use that

Comment: btw the in kernal thing might be the right thing to do but I'm so new to Python and programming that I have no clue how to go about that

Comment: As far as I can see the micropython based driver the code is straight forward. Taking into account that it exists and kernel also has driver (though for serdev) it wouldn't be big deal to create driver either in kernel (preferred) or in user space. If you can't do it yourself ask freelancers. I dunno how much it may cost, but taking above into account I can say ~$150 is a fair price (and no, it's not me, who is willing get job done).